# Validity of a dereferenced char[] pointer outside method scope

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have a corrupted char[] on my embedded system (Arduino) and I suspect a portion of code. Here is the code (well, I have tried to conceptualize it, I did not try to compile what you read). 
Basically, the question is : can I store a pointer to a "abcde" object outside a method scope (I don't know how to name "abcd", is it a constant array of char ?)

```
class A {
    public:
    void store(char *ptr_char) {
        m_ptr=ptr_char;
    }
    void useit() {
        // is *m_ptr valid here ?
        printf("%s",m_ptr);
    }

private :
    char *m_ptr;
}

class B :  A {
    void remember() {
        store ("string to remember");
    }
}

main () {
    B obj;

    obj.remember();
    obj.useit();
}
```

I observe corruption of *m_ptr memory, "string to remember" is corrupted in real life code (with other objects in memory).
My C personal memory tells me that it is not valid to keep a reference to an unallocated object. I beleive "string to remember" was on the stack during remember() method execution, but there is no guaranty is will be available after remember() is exited, right ?

The whole thing is : I don't know how C++ treats those things between quotes :)

Comment: This code is valid because string literals are stored in static location, but this seems not a good practice.

Comment: `obj.remember();` cannot compile.

Comment: Also if you want to accept string literals then you should be using a `const char *` not a `char *`.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the fact that your code snippet cannot be the *real* testcase (because `A` has no member function named `remember()`), **there is nothing fundamentally wrong with what you've shown us**. You're storing a pointer to a string literal, and string literals last forever.

However, your compiler should be warning you to store it as a `const char*` — it's actually illegal not to since 2011.

It's likely you're corrupting the memory taken up by this literal, and there's no way for us to know how without an MCVE. **Perhaps, after you've added the missing `const`, your compiler can catch your error for you.** But this is by no means guaranteed.

Also, don't forget your return type for `main`.

Comment: Ok, you have made me change my mind. I'll invest the necessary time to give you a MCVE, not just a code snippet that try to describes the issue. And my bad, the library I use declares const char[] as you stated it. I'll be back with real material, thanks !

Comment: @Jean-yvesLeseigneur: _Always_ present your [MCVE]. This is why!